# What happen when modify state in setState?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
export default function Raffle(){
/*......*/

  setCandidates(() => {
    candidates.splice(winnerIdx,1) //(*)
    return [...candidates];
    })
  }

}
```

at (*) line, setCandidates Function remove 2 candidates. but below is run as expected.

```
    setCandidates(() => {
      let remain = [...candidates];
      remain.splice(winnerIdx,1);
      return [...remain];
    })
```

I don't know why the splice method activate twice in first case.

what happened when i modified state in setState function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a callback to your set state call, and then copy the argument, not mutate it. Mutating state is generally not good.

```
setCandidates((oldCandidates) => {
      let remain = [...oldCandidates];
      remain.splice(winnerIdx,1);
      return [...remain];
})
```

I'm not sure why *exactly* you were having the problem you were having, but dealing with state this way is much safer and will avoid any weird behavior.

Comment: Thank you for answering despite my messed english. I find the reason was React strict mode.